# Cross browser issue (iframe sizing)

Tags: html, css, iframe, cross-browser, resize

I am displaying pages from an external site (that I own) in an `iframe` in one of my pages. It's all fine except when viewed in `Opera` with the browser window size reduced (not widescreen), when the `iframe` shrinks and squashes the content. It works in widescreen (maximize browser window), and is OK in `IE7, Firefox, Chrome` and `Safari` in maximize and reduced window size.

I have set the frame dimensions in the HTML and have nested the `iframe` in a `div` which is larger than the `iframe` via the css.

Is this a peculiar bug to Opera or is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue with `iframe` sizing on our web app main page, although in IE6. The solution was to trap the `window.onresize` event and call a JavaScript function to appropriately size the `iframe`. `content` is the name of the `iframe` we want sized. Also note that we are using ASP.Net AJAX's `$get` which translates to `document.getElementById()`

```
window.onresize=resizeContentFrame;
resizeContentFrame();

function resizeContentFrame() {
    setFrameHeight($get('content'));
}

function setFrameHeight(f) {
    if(isDefined(f)) {
        var h=document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        h-=(HEADER_HEIGHT+CONTENT_PADDING+5);
        f.style.height=h+'px';
    }
}
```